# Extracting frames from video using opencv Python in Google cloud functions

Tags: python, opencv, video, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to extract frames at particular timestamp from video using opencv-python. The code seems to work in my local environment. code snippet below,

```
import cv2

path = r'C:\Users\abc\def.mp4'
final_path = r'C:\Users\abc'

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,2*1000)   # set pointer at 2sec(2000ms)
success,image = vidcap.read()
if success:
    framefilepath = final_path + "\\frame_2.jpg"
    cv2.imwrite(framefilepath, image) 

print("Frame extraction Successful :{}".format(success))
```

Here is the output..

```
Frame extraction Successful :True
```

But when I am writing cloud functions in Python for the same, it is unable to extract. It doesn't throw any error but extraction is unsuccessful each time.(Code snippet below..)

```
uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(input_bucket_name, source_file)
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(uri)
vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 2000)   # just cue to 2 sec. position
success,image = vidcap.read()

print("The extraction process is successful : {}".format(success))
```

Here is the output,

```
The extraction process is successful : False
```

[Here is output from cloud function logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ABPL.png)

I tried with different file sizes but the issue remains. Please help.

Comment: Where is the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the question? Please include it to the question. Also make sure to read [How do I ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: In the local code you are accessing local storage (C:Users...)  I would try first testing the code accessing the bucket URL in your local environment to rule out an issue with accessing the file in cloud storage, I would also suggest implementing a way to check if VideoCapture is actually able to access the file, if it doesn't, one thing to check is file permissions in cloud storage, cloud functions use a default service [account](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/function-identity) that should have permissions to access the file

Comment: when testing locally, the cloud sdk uses an [account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/list) that was specified when setting up the environment which should also have permissions to download the file from cloud storage. Here is the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control) for learning about permissions in cloud storage